# sending data to javascript from android (droid/native) in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i am a new to phone-gap. i simply wants to send some data say a string "hello", to JavaScript and show it there. and after showing the string, JavaScript should return a string say "hello again" to android, and android will Toast that from here.

i searched a lot of threads here in 'stackoverflow', but not able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding you need to implement a custom plugin to interact with android code to do what you want, look at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins

Comment: i tried this on my samsung galaxy grand, but it is showing no exec method at line 863 cordava 2.8.0, then when i check that line it says to go with PROMPT mode(wont work either), and samsung galaxy problem is mentioned there in cordova in comments.